# Passing through StaticResource style defined in XAML in C# codebehind

Tags: c#, xaml

I am building a WPF application. XAML used for front end and C# for code behind

I have the following section of code that generates my XAML for me dynamically.

```
if (station_item.Checker_Setup.First().Checker_Log.OrderByDescending(log => log.date).First().Status.status_key == 2)
                    {
                        Path path = new Path();
                        path.Data = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, 0, 19, 21), 3, 3);
                        path.Style = "{StaticResource statusIndicatorRed}";
                        TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
                        block.Text = station_item.station_name;
                        WrapBox.Children.Add(path);
                        WrapBox.Children.Add(block);
                    }
```

However where I have

```
path.Style = "{StaticResource statusIndicatorRed}";
```

I get the following error

*Cannot implicitly convert type String  to System.Windows.Style*

The style is defined in my MainWindow.xaml as follows

```
<Style x:Key="statusIndicatorRed" TargetType="Path">
        <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#B2203D" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="19px" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowDuration" Value="30000" />
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Help" />
</Style>
```

How would I pass this style through in my code behind? Is this even a good way to do things?

Comment: You would need to place the resource where your code-behind set up has access to it. For example `path.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["statusIndicatorRed"];` if the resource is defined in App.xaml or in a ResourceDictionary referenced by App.Xaml.

Comment: Aha! I thought the issue could be that the code behind had no way of seeing where this style was defined. Thanks for the help I shall make the changes needed then.

Comment: @Silvermind would best practice be to define my style in a seperate file referenced by App.Xaml?

Comment: Yes, using seperate ResourceDictionaries to group styles is a good idea.

Answer (score 6):

This is what I did to fix the issue:

I created a new ResourceDictionary named Styles.xaml

In my App.xaml I referenced the resource as follows

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles.xaml" />
</Application.Resources>
```

In my codebehind I called the resource as follows

```
path.Style = (Style)App.Current.Resources["statusIndicatorRed"];
```

Comment: +1 Consider adding the relevant part of `Styles.xaml`.